# Como criar esse tipo de relacionamento usando as Models Django

Tags: python, django, modelagem

Após ver uma modelagem que eu deveria implementar no Django, fiquei um pouco confuso e vou explicar o que tentei fazer e o que me foi enviado.
A imagem a seguir é o relacionamento que devo implementar em Django
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que tentei fazer foi:

```py
class Contato(models.Model):
    pessoa = models.OneToOneField(Pessoa)

class Pessoa(models.Model):
    contato = models.ForeignKey(Contato)
```

Porém isso não funciona, ambas as classes estão no mesmo arquivo. Li a documentação de ManyToManyField, OneToOneField e ForeignKey, mas o que me deixa confuso é o modelo querer a varialvel nas duas classes, em modelos anteriores que vi existia essa mesma relação, porém a varialvel só existia em uma das classes. Qual a maneira correta de implementar isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entendo que uma pessoa pode ter um ou mais contatos, certo?

Dê uma olhada abaixo:

```
from django.db import models

class Pessoa(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Contato(models.Model):
    contato = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pessoa = models.ForeignKey(Pessoa, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.contato

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['pessoa']
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Olá, Paulo, depois de realizar alguns testes eu já tinha chegado na mesma conclusão que você, então vou considerar sua resposta como a correta visto que a implementação foi parecida. Obrigado.